# Asio drivers (hercules dj air)

Tags: drivers, helpfile

I recently installed Ubuntu but now, I want to use my hercules dj air. Why? Because it have something called DAC or idk. Anyway, sound quality > better.
I don't know what to do. (I don't want to install wine, asiowine or something similar)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice DJ program called [Mixxx](http://www.mixxx.org/), which is also available for Ubuntu. To install the latest version, open a terminal and execute these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mixxx/mixxx
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mixxx libportaudio2
```

Mixxx comes with many DJ table setups preinstalled. I think it has a preset for the Hercules DJ Air, but I don't know how well it's already set up. Try to just connect the device, open Mixxx, go into Preferences and set up the device by selecting it from the list in the according menu.

Comment: Well, as I see it's working but after 5 sec "the application Mixxx has closed unexpectedly" :( help?

Comment: Try running Mixxx from a terminal and report any errors shown.

Comment: When I start mixxx from terminal it's working fine but, the volume is too low and,I want to use asio with spotify...

Comment: Have a look at this according ASIO: http://www.head-fi.org/t/183861/linux-and-asio (I doubt you'll need to use ASIO, ALSA already has a low latency, and the german Wikipedia tells me it's a good alternative).

Comment: ALSA looks good but, I don't know from where to start, what to do, etc. I'm new in linux world. And, btw... can you tell me how to install Steam? I got it but doesn't start.

Comment: For ALSA, ask Google for a tutorial on how to configure a ASIO device... For steam, please ask a new question.